# Como realizar soma por linha em um datagridview em c#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, preciso de uma ajuda, tenho uma datagridview que contem uma coluna de Tipo Moeda e uma coluna de total Moeda. Na coluna Tipo Moeda eu posso ter até 3 tipos de moeda, moeda euro, moeda dolar e moeda real. Agora eu preciso fazer uma soma por moeda. Ex somar tudo que for moeda euro e mostrar no txtboxEuro, depois somar tudo que for moeda dolar e mostrar no textboxDolar. Como posso fazer isso

segue a tela do datagridview.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue meu código.

```
private void ListaGrid()
        {
            conex.Open();
            string strSQL = @"SELECT DISTINCT
                            SY.YF_DESC_SI                               AS [TIPO MOEDA],
                            RTRIM(SC.C7_PRODUTO) + ' - ' + SC.C7_DESCRI AS PRODUTO,
                            SUM(SC.C7_QUANT)                            AS QTDA, 
                            SUM(SC.C7_TOTAL * SC.C7_TXMOEDA)            AS TOTAL,
                            SUM(SC.C7_TOTAL)                            AS [TOTAL MOEDA]
                   FROM  SC7010 AS SC
                   INNER JOIN SM2010 AS SM WITH (NOLOCK) ON SM.M2_DATA = SC.C7_EMISSAO
                   INNER JOIN SA2010 AS SA WITH (NOLOCK) ON SA.A2_COD = SC.C7_FORNECE
                   INNER JOIN SYF010 AS SY WITH (NOLOCK) ON SY.YF_MOEFAT = SC.C7_MOEDA
                   WHERE SC.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' 
 AND SC.C7_EMISSAO BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '" + txtDtInicial.Text + "', 103) AND CONVERT(datetime,'" + txtDtFinal.Text + "', 103) AND SA.A2_COD = '" + txtCodFornec.Text + "' GROUP BY SC.C7_PRODUTO, SC.C7_DESCRI, SY.YF_DESC_SI ORDER BY RTRIM(SC.C7_PRODUTO) + ' - ' + SC.C7_DESCRI";

            comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conex);

            try
            {
                SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
                DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
                dados.Fill(dtLista);

                DGW_PedComprasPic.DataSource = dtLista;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a serem encontrados");
            }

            double QTDA = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow rowKG in DGW_PedComprasPic.Rows)
            {
                QTDA += Convert.ToDouble(rowKG.Cells["QTDA"].Value);
            }
            txtProdkg.Text = Convert.ToString(QTDA);
            txtProdkg.Text = QTDA.ToString("N2");

            double TotalReal = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow rowR in DGW_PedComprasPic.Rows)
            {
                TotalReal += Convert.ToDouble(rowR.Cells["TOTAL"].Value);
            }
            txtReal.Text = Convert.ToString(TotalReal);
            txtReal.Text = TotalReal.ToString("C");

            conex.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com `LINQ` fica muito bom fazer isso, e simples.

```
decimal totalEuro = DGW_PedComprasPic.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
.Where(t => t.Cells[/*Nome ou indice da coluna com o tipo da moeda */].Value.ToString() == "Euro")
.Sum(t => Convert.ToDecimal(t.Cells[/*Nome ou indice da coluna de com o valor */].Value));

txtBoxTotalEuro.Text = totalEuro; // Ajustar para valor monetário.
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção Alex, mas como sou novo ainda em c# não estou sabendo onde colocar o seu código dentro do meu código acima, não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar o código que vc me passou no meu código.

Comment: Coloque após o `conex.Close();`. Lembre-se que tem que fazer isso para cada tipo de moeda, no meu exemplo é o Euro. Veja também os nomes que eu coloquei no meu exemplo, ajuste eles para sua necessidade, lembrando também que eles são case sensitive, o `"Euro"` que digitei no meu exemplo pode não funcionar se estiver no formato errado (maisculo/minusculo).

Comment: Alex fiz do jeito que me explicou e mesmo assim não esta fazendo a soma não.

Comment: Ele dá algum erro? Lembre-se que o a parte do Cast é assim `Cast<DataGridViewRow>()` ao invés do que você postou na sua resposta `Cast()`.

Comment: O cast esta certinho no código, mas não da nenhum erro não quando debugo passa normalmente mas com valor 0 no txtbox.

Comment: Primeiro troque o decimal por double no meu código... se não funcionar troque o `Convert.ToDecimal` por `decimal.Parse` também no meu código. Talvez ele não esteja conseguindo ler o valor formatado com ponto e virgula.

Comment: Alex bom dia, fiz todas as alterações que vc me pediu e ainda não esta somando, no seu codigo não tem que ser feito um foreach para passar linha a linha no datagridviwer.

Comment: Confirme se a coluna que contém o tipo da moeda ("Euro", "Dolar") é o índice zero mesmo, tente colocar o nome da coluna ao invés do indice. Tudo indica que ele não está conseguindo encontrar este valor "EURO". Confirme também se é tudo maiúsculo.

Comment: Esta tudo certo ja teste com o nome da coluna e também com o numero do indice da coluna também, e mesmo assim nada de somar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65833/discussion-between-junior-guerreiro-and-murarialex).